# stop undeploying of application on shutting/restart down Jboss server

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

Recently I have deployed couple of applications in Jboss 7.1.0 EAP. Whenever I shutdown or restarts the Jboss server, application undeploys and again starts deploying, because of this, we have to wait for longer time to access the deployed applications, which is not acceptable.

Currently I am deploying applications via JBOSS CLI command interface.

Can we stop this undeployment of applications on shutting down or restart of jboss EAP?

Comment: Consider the deployment/undeployment as the startup/shutdown phases of the applications. I don't believe you can somehow skip that. There are other ways to speed up the start and stop of your server though, such as removing subsystems you don't rely on.

Comment: Also since you're using JBoss EAP (as opposed to wildfly/previously JBoss AS) you must have access to redhat support ; you should probably provide them your domain/standalone.xml and ask them how you can speed up your startup/shutdown.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JBoss per se, it's "as designed". JBoss like any other application server are nothing but a set of tools standardized to let the developpers concentrate on their actual application instead of recreating the wheel like datasources and other usual objects. Remember that your application is actually running within a JVM, which stands for Java Virtual Machine. Like any virtual machine, it has to boot up, loading the classes and objects in its memory and so on, it takes time.

Comment: I don't think you can skip deployment at startup. It would be better if you can optimize the application and server configurations to reduce startup time. Also, try to reduce the number of restarts required.